# ChartJs как добавить подписи к сгруппированным столбцам

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Сделал на react-chartjs горизонтальную диаграмму с группированными столбцами, и вот столкнулся с проблемой что для группы название поставил,а к самим столбцам не могу. Название для столбцов во всех группах одинаковое, например для первого столбца "первый" для второго "второй" и так в каждой группе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]